# Which one sounds "more English": Being/after 15 minutes in the icy water he turned blue

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

Which of the following two sentences sounds "more English":

> Being 15 minutes in the icy water he turned blue.
>   After 15 minutes in the icy water he turned blue.

And if both of them sound "pretty English" do they differ in meaning or style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one (after 15 minutes...he turned blue) is the more natural of the two.  With the **being** version, you'd want to move "15 minutes" after "water", "Being in the icy water *for 15 minutes*". And you can eliminate **being**: "In the icy water for fifteen minutes, he turned blue."

You could also say:

> In the icy water for fifteen minutes, he had turned blue by the time we got him out.

In your "after 15 minutes" version, you're describing the situation and the *ensuing* result. In this version, with the past perfect, we describe the result after-the-fact, as one  fully realized as of the time we got him out.

Comment: I'm afraid not to have understood your last sentence completely: "we describe the result after-the-fact, as one fully realized as of the time we got him out". My understanding so far: result = "he is blue", fact = "we got him out", "one fully realized" - who/what "one"?; is "as ... as .." a special grammatical construct in this case?

Comment: In my example, "he had turned blue" is the fully realized thing. "By the time we got him out" is a time-reference.   He was not turning blue. He did not turn blue.  He was *already* (and completely) blue by the time we got him out.  That is what the past perfect indicates there (already completed).